Override columnDefinition in hibernate
I'm having an issue where a JPAentity I'm importing from another library has a field that's hardcoded to be columnDefinition = TEXT but I'd like that field to be LONGTEXT in the db. I am not allowed to edit to the JPAentity itself, nor can I just make my own. Is there a way to force this via a custom dialect somehow without getting schema validation errors on startup (due to the schema saying longtext while the jpaentity says text)?
What I tried:
public class CustomSQLDialect extends MySQL5Dialect {

    public CustomSQLDialect() {
        super();
        registerColumnType(Types.VARCHAR, "LONGTEXT");
        registerColumnType(Types.LONGVARCHAR, "LONGTEXT");
    }

    @Override
    public String getTypeName(int code, long length, int precision, int scale) throws HibernateException {
        if (code == Types.VARCHAR || code == Types.LONGVARCHAR) {
            return "LONGTEXT";
        }
        return super.getTypeName(code, length, precision, scale);
    }

    @Override
    public SqlTypeDescriptor getSqlTypeDescriptorOverride(int sqlCode) {
        if (sqlCode == Types.VARCHAR || sqlCode == Types.LONGVARCHAR) {
            return LongVarcharTypeDescriptor.INSTANCE;
        }
        return super.getSqlTypeDescriptorOverride(sqlCode);
    }
}


do you work with code-first or sql-first?

code-first I suppose, this is in a non-spring java service.
